# LCD Shield and Arduino

Tags: lcd

I am trying to use a load cell (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13331?_ga=1.55586472.2060096590.1479826091) and an HX711 chip with an arduino and LCD shield to display weight values on the LCD shield  when weight is added to the load cell. Does anyone know how I can connect all of these together?

Mainly, how do I connect the HX711 to the arduino while the LCD shield is already on the arduino?

Any help is welcomed , thanks.

Here is the LCD shield I am using I am using:

LCD Shield- https://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=51

Arduino- not sure which type of arduino to use.

Comment: You need to do a bit more research on your own. That load cell + HX711 is just a sensor and it connects to the Arduino in a way that many sensors do. Use Google to find projects like a thermometer with LCD readout and see how the sensor is connected there. Also research the differences (and commonalities) between the Arduino boards, that information can easily be found.

Answer (score 1):

Note: While looking at specifications can infer compatibility, there is no substitute for prototyping.  It is always better to try something then ask for suggestions if it does not work as expected.

That said, I would suggest to look at the LCD you specified.  The LCD's physical shape appears to lock you into a legacy Arduino Uno layout.

On the LCD's web page is a list of pins used.

On the [HX711 sparkfun.com web page](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide) is a diagram of pins used when using their HX711 software.

Check if there are any conflicts.  Even if there are none, it does not mean there will be no conflicts within the software you will need to run the LCD and the HX711.  You will have to either find someone who has successfully done exactly what you want to do or examine all the software involved your self.  Of course you could simply prototype the project to see if it works.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I have been looking at this video on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pzZ0NfQmsY) and it is exactly what I am trying to build however I cannot tell what he is using to connect his HX711 to the arduino. It appears the LCD shield is attached on top on the arduino, but I cannot see where the white wire to the arduino is connected. Any ideas?

Comment: He does not say, does he?  He does not even list his software - as there are youtube comments asking for it.  So it is not a good source of information.  Until you are more familiar with working with Arduinos, you should probably find reputable sources which publish good documentation and answer questions by email or in forums. I would suggest looking more closely at the link in the answer.  I believe if you do you will find not only where to connect the sensor but also where to get the software for the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straight forward.

1. Read the data sheet to find out how you can communicate to hx711. There are tons of example code out there. I have a set of them for my own use as well. The device is quite simple to program too.
2. Find a few pins on the Arduino and configure your code, or others code, to use those pins.
3. I corporate that into your existing code.

That's like how you would approach 99.99 percent of the embedded project - read the data sheet and Code to the data sheet.

If you do run into specific issues, ask them here.